# bash - omitting if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm sorry for likely trivial question but i start learning Bash two days ago. I'm still newbie :).

```
if [ ! -d $backup_directory ]; then
        echo $'Backup device is not mounted or is mounted somewhere elese\a!'
        echo "Press enter when sdc device mounted to /mnt/sdc1 or past alternative path:"
        while [ ! -e $backup_directory ]; do
                alter_dev_path="" 
                read $alter_dev_path
                if [ "$alter_dev_path" != "" ]; then
                        $backup_directory=$alter_dev_path
                        $destination_directory=$alter_dev_path+"/sh-backup"
                        $result_path=$destination_directory+"/programming-base"
                fi
        done
fi
```

Thats is if statement from my backup script. I want program to ask me about device mount directory. But while loop is just omitting if statement inside with no effect.
Thanks, Siery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read a value:

```
read $alter_dev_path  # Wrong
read alter_dev_path   # Correct
```

To assign a value:

```
$destination_directory=$alter_dev_path+"/sh-backup"  # Wrong
destination_directory="$alter_dev_path/sh-backup"    # Correct
```

Comment: Thank you, it's just what i needed ^^.